# Is there a way of adjusting the width of a <select> according to the length of the selected <option> within?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to achieve something like Amazon has to the left of its Search bar (eventhough they are using divs).

I guess css alone doesn't do the trick. I figure javascript is needed to count the letters of the selected  and multiply it for some value (maybe 3px?) and apply that as width of the parent .

Comment: Don't know Amazon. Could you please describe the desired behaviour exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `width: auto;` and `display: inline-block;` to the div that will represent option item and it will resize automatically depending on it's content.

http://jsfiddle.net/JKxTQ/1/

UPDATE 2:

Use div as an width indicator so you can use it's width to resize your select box:

http://jsfiddle.net/JKxTQ/6/

Comment: Thanx. Although interesting, it doesn't solve the <select> width issue. I need the the <select> to vary its width. Thanks again!

Comment: This is great. There's still an issue though:

The width of the <select> is not consistent between short and long <option>s. I'm talking about the space it leaves to the right for the browser drop-down arrow to appear.

I tried different values for "40" and it's inconsistent every time. (try with a short and a much longer <option>).

I guess it's because it's translating each character into 1px and then adding 40. Is there a way to define a desired "character to pixel ratio"?

Comment: I guess determining the width based on character count will always display inconsistently across different words, as characters are not the same width. So there might not be a solution to this, and that's why Amazon used <div>s instead.

Comment: @Nicus that is because div and select must have same font-family and font-size.

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome's 'Inspect Element', I've only found that using *width: auto*, on both the select as the div it migh be surrounded with, should do the trick.